# Raspberry 3 / chromium webRTC video quality

Tags: chromium, webrtc

I am currently working on having a web page that allows the user to see a live stream of his / her webcam and then take a snapshot (so nothing special).

Everything is fine, but on a RaspberryPi 3 running raspbian with chromium browser latest (for that distro), I can't go above a resolution of 640 x 480 using the constraints.

If I go any higher than these values, the image will simply not show on the page.

some code snippet:

```
    var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        //width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        //height: { min: 768, ideal: 960, max: 1440 }
        width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        height: { min: 480, ideal: 960, max: 1440 }
    }
};

[...]

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
      constraints,
      function(stream) {
        if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
          video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        } else {
          var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
          video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
        video.play();
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log("An error occured! " + err);
      }
    );
```

Does anyone have an Idea what I might want to look into ?
I've searched the web for the past 2 weeks but didn't find anything helpful so far...

The camera (Logitech HD C910) is displaying fullhd just fine in cheese...

All Ideas are highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has a bug and the rpi needs a few extra flags set. This solved it for me:

Add Drivers:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
i2c-dev
snd-bcm2835
bcm2835-v4l2
```

Add extra V4l2 video driver flag (for Chromium to pick up the camera):

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/bcm2835-v4l2.conf
options bcm2835-v4l2 gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1
```

Here's the link: https://planb.nicecupoftea.org/2016/10/24/a-presence-robot-with-chromium-webrtc-raspberry-pi-3-and-easyrtc/

Comment: Wow, cool, I'll re-activate the PI for this project and give it a try